# Unstable DC voltage ~ 300v to regulated 120V conversion

Tags: voltage, dc, windturbine

I need your advice for transforming DC voltage which is coming directly from many bridge rectifiers connected the pluses and minuses (from custom made multi phase wind alternator).

At the bridges output, I get from 150 to 350 volts (depends from the speed of the wind).

Because I got many phases I decide to bridge them all and then to use some kind of shunt limiter or buck converter or some circuit that may be do the job, to drop the DC voltage anywhere from 12 to 120 volts but with as much current possible.

Edit: Or if there is a efficient way to drop the AC voltage before the transformation to DC somehow.

Can you help? thanks alot guys!

Comment: What is your specific question and remember that nobody here knows your skill level so it’s impossible to guess what you might understand and might not.

Comment: Why do you have so many phases? Are there more than one turbines? Why is the voltage so high when you want a much lower voltage? Anything else to tell us that will help us help you?

Comment: Just as a "one-off" suggestion, google up Roman Black and buck converters. You need something like 4 A. Which is probably not in the ballpark of converters with his name attached. But it should provide some food for thought, regardless.

Comment: The alternator have 27 phases, it is designed that way. I cannot make them less as it is right now. So I have to find a way to collect that energy and get it at low DC voltage high amperage type, so I can use it to charge batteries and inverters etc. Where I need your help is at the manipulation of this output voltage.  Is there a way to connect all to a transformer/s and get 1 phase somehow? Because I guess it is easier to drop AC voltage than DC without much losses. As is now, all phases are bridged and their outs are in parallel and I get 150-350 Volts DC.

Comment: I believe that each phase will give about 1 Amp at 12v average.  So I need more than 27 Amps at lets say 12v dc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of the Roman black buck design, This maybe the solution! thank you Jonk!

Answer (score 1):

The "with as much current as possible" means that you can't use a shunt regulator, you need to use a "buck" dc-dc converter.

Oh, and to get as much current **as possible**, look for a converter with 100% efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for replying! The problem is that I can't find any step-down buck converter, ready made or as a module at the market. to have input150-350v and output 80-120v. If you know any seller please send me the link! thanks!

Comment: Sorry, we try not to recommend specific products here. And your edit contradicts the original question. Do you need as much current as possible or do you only need half of the input power?

Comment: Ah sorry! I didn't realize it! I need as much current as possible.. I said I need only 400 watts because to give 700w or more it needs alot of wind that will never get.. I can make it if I have a schematic or a drawing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First in your defenition you have not specified an exact voltage. Most converters have maximum efficiency at a limited voltage range.
Now if you are feeding a constant load ,then 150v output will draw maximum current which will drop more voltage than when the alternator output is 350 volts. If that drop is more than the buck converters minimum input voltage then the converter will loose regulation. In that case you would have to use a buck boost converter.

If I were you I would wind my alternator for say 24 or 30 volts, charge up a battery bank(or directly) use a dcdc converter to get 120 volts

Comment: I agree with you to use a high power, high voltage input, buck converter, but I can't find any...  I wish I could wind up all coils to give less voltage, but is impossible to do it. This alternator has 72 high voltage coils (many turns).  Unfortunately I have to use this alternator. :(

Comment: Necessity is the mother of inventions. Follow that and build a converter on your own. There is plenty of resource in the web. I still recommend you use a lower voltage alternator. If you must use the current one then try a multistep buck converter since as the difference in input and output voltage increases it becomes difficult to control the duty cycle.